# Error al insertar datos con tablas relacionadas

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Les traigo problema que me surge. Estoy haciendo algo en Visual Studio y resulta que quiero insertar datos en una tabla por medio de un botón, pero me sale el siguiente error cuando hago click:

> "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_ventas_detalle_productos". The conflict occurred in database
>   "cobros", table "dbo.productos", column 'codproducto'. The statement
>   has been terminated.

[image: datos_de_tablas]

[image: codigo]
Alguien sabe qué puede ser?, les hago ver que datos tienen las tablas en que me sale el error y también la parte del código para que vean como funciona.

DESDE YA MUCHAS GRACIAS!

Comment: Hola! Procura compartir tu código, los datos de prueba, los mensajes de error y la estructura de las tablas como texto. Ver estas imágenes puede llegar a ser muy difícil y replicar errores a partir de imágenes puede ser dispendioso o ignorar problemas tipográficos que puedas tener. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes

Comment: Sobre el error que comentas, cuando hay un insert en conflicto con una FK, significa que la tabla de la que se referencia esa FK no tiene un registro con el valor que intentas insertar. EL orden es importante.

Answer (score 0):

Estás insertando la venta de un producto que no tienes dado de alta en la tabla de productos.
También tienes un código totalmente abierto a inyección de SQL.

Comment: Hola Luis Cazares! si tengo productos dados de alta, son solo 3:
1, 00001, Sillas Eames Cross Wood, 1200,00
2,00002, Microondas BGH Quick Chef 23 L B2223 PLata, 1000,00
8,00003, SECARROPA KOH I NOOR A-665/2, 5000,00
Y tenes razón por lo de la inyección, quizás la haga con procedimientos almacenados

Comment: Pero hay al menos uno que no está en la tabla de productos. Parametriza tu cadena de SQL a menos de que quieras correr el riesgo de perder tu base de datos.

Comment: Están todos 3 códigos que quiero usar, no sé cuál puede ser el problema. Igual ya voy a parametrizar como decís.